# Posso colocar um operador ternário dentro de outro ternário em java?

Tags: java

Posso colocar um operador ternário dentro de outro ternário em java?

(num1 == num2)? System.out.println("Digite numeros diferentes! "):maior = (num1 > num2)? num1:num2;

Comment: sim vc pode, olha o conteudo da resposta duplicada p mais detalhes

Comment: Poder acredito que pode, mas evite. Na hora você vai entender mas depois vai acabar ficando difícil de ler.